# Exchange mailbox rule export and import

Tags: outlook, migration, exchangewebservices

I am curious to know if it is even possible to export mailbox rule from one tenant (tenant A) to a new tenant (tenant B). This is after Tenant A has been migrated to Tenant B.

I have tested 3 different methods with no success.

1. Microsoft Graph API: The code works but it doesn’t allow us to import from A to B. If I export from A and import to A teanant or different account on that tenant it works.
   `{ "error": { "code": "MessageRuleValidationError", "message": "ErrorCode: 'InvalidValue', Message: 'No mailbox with such guid.', Field: 'Action.CopyToFolder', Value: 'AQMkAGM0NWJhZDMxLTYyNmUtNGIxNy1hMmQ4LWRjMDlkMDQ0AGM1OWUALgAAAymAV8m5TCtGuN0NJDnVw4gBAAi19MYDG7VEuldE4lOvZFEAAAIBQgAAAA=='.", "innerError": { "request-id": "ca3c9777-8ddc-41f0-8790-938294661ebc", "date": "2018-12-28T06:13:23" } } }`
2. Manual Process: I was able to export and import within the same environment on multiple accounts but once I imported onto Tenant B it failed 
   ADAccount01@sjhtestad2.org ) becuase I only had access to one PHS account.
3. New-InboxRule Method:   I used the exported file and try to import using New-InboxRule and I got the following error 
   `The specified mailbox "AAMkADZkZTU5ZTgzLTUzNDUtNDAwNy1hYTBlLTFkNmVhNWFhMzk2YwAuAAAAAABZtDH804khSZs_9ansnr8hAQACqSktPeE9SrZAHfG14OfYAAARNiPIAAA=" doesn't exist.

   - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-InboxRule], ManagementObjectNotFoundException`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't Export and Import, because the Identifiers used for Mailbox Folder, address lists, recipients (eg if they are in the Native Address format) etc are only work in the Mailbox where the Rule was created.

You would be better investing the time to create a process that create a new rule using the rule from the Mailbox you want to export from as a Template. But you will need to write a process to find folders if its a Move rule etc but its not that much effort and will be a lot more reliable then what you trying to do.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "create a process that create a new rule using the rule from the Mailbox you want to export from as a Template. But you will need to write a process to find folders if its a Move rule etc"

Comment: Create a New rule and for each of the properties use the values from the other rule except any identifiers which won't be valid